# VBA Excel - Move entire row based on 2 criteria to new sheet & NEW LINE

Tags: excel, vba

I had previously asked with help regarding moving an entire row based on 2 criteria to a new sheet; however, upon doing so, the code given (love the help!) will overwrite the previous line moved. I need it to add to the next available row. For instance, in Worksheet "Tasks", I mark the task complete. That row automatically moves to the worksheet "Completed Tasks" starting on A3. When I mark the next task complete, it ALSO moves to worksheet "Completed Tasks" on A3. I need it to move to A4 and so on.

Here is the code that was given.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' check if value modified in column F
If Target.Column = 6 Then
    ' ~~~ Call Sub that moves rows from "Tasks" worksheet to "Completes Tasks" worksheet ~~~
    MoveRowsToCompletedTasks
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Option Explicit

Sub MoveRowsToCompletedTasks()

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet 
Dim CopyRng As Range  
Dim i as Long, lastRow As Long

' Set the source and target sheets
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tasks")
Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Completed Tasks")

With sourceSheet
    ' Find the last row in the source sheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row in the source sheet
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        ' Check if cell in column F contains "Complete" or "Discontinued"
        If .Cells(i, "F").Value = "Complete" Or .Cells(i, "F").Value = "Discontinued" Then
            If CopyRng Is Nothing Then
                Set CopyRng = .Cells(i, "F")
            Else
                Set CopyRng = Application.Union(CopyRng, .Cells(i, "F"))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With    

' make sure there's at least 1 row that needs to be moved
If Not CopyRng Is Nothing Then
    CopyRng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    CopyRng.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the first column (A) always filled?

Comment: Hi @FunThomas. Yes, it would be.

Comment: If A3 is filled, `targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` should locate cell A4. `MoveRowsToCompletedTasks` validate all data in column F and copy `Complete/Discontinued`, it leads duplicated records in `targetSheet`.

Comment: Here is [ANOTHER WAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631363/how-to-copy-a-line-in-excel-using-a-specific-word-and-pasting-to-another-excel-s/11633207#11633207) to move the rows without looping ;)

Comment: I see you are finding last row in the source sheet based on `Col F`. Why not use the same thing for targetsheet? `targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1)` BTW, if you are not sure which column may have data (*A or F for calculating last row*) then use `.Find` to calculate the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Hi. When I change the targetSheet from "A" to "F", I get an error. It would be great to utilize that column instead of A but I am not entirely sure how to do that. I am an extreme beginner and am still trying to read and understand the code as given. IF I have something in column A and column F is either "Complete" or "Discontinued", it will cut/paste the entire row from the sourceSheet to the targetSheet; however, if there is nothing in column A and column F is either "Complete" or "Discontinued", it will overwrite the last row (which is not what I want to happen).

Comment: `I change the targetSheet from "A" to "F", I get an error` What error?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Can you please update the post above with the current that code you are using?

Comment: The code is updated.